# Does email queue affect speed of email traffic for other users on shared server?

Tags: server, email, postfix, smtp, exim

I have a guy on the server who hit the mailbox storage limit, so the inbound emails got stuck in the email queue. How urgently do I need to act on this problem and does he threaten the performance for other users? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email queue is not first-in, first-out.  If certain items remain stuck in the queue, other items that arrived later can still be processed.